How to change drag amount with different scale to each other?
I am trying to finish a custom slider, which is not an ordinary one. It involves pressing inside and outside by dragging a circle on the screen. The drag amount of the circle is scaled down by a factor of 10. I've already completed the circle-dragging part, and the custom slider works as I expected when dragging the circle.
However, the issue arises when I try to reverse the process by dragging the custom slider itself. I have finished every part except for reverse-engineering the .onChange(of: percentageDX) part in CustomSliderView. I have been struggling with this for hours, trying about 50 different trial-and-error attempts, but I can't wrap my head around it. I need help to complete the missing part for knobGesture in CustomSliderView.
Here's a bit of context on how the code works: I have a screen in the app that serves as a measuring tool to find out the percentage of the circle’s drag. I then send this percentage to CustomSliderView and scale it down by 10 times. This action reduces the displacement amount by a factor of 10 on the slider, allowing it to work properly with the circle's dragging. You can try dragging the circle to see that when the circle has zero drag or displacement left or right, the slider is at 100%. As the circle starts moving left or right, the slider begins pressing in the opposite direction.
Now, I want to make it so that dragging the slider will reverse this pressing process, allowing it to gradually depress back to 100% as the circle returns to its original position.



import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var lastCircleOffset: CGSize = CGSize()
    @State private var currentCircleOffset: CGSize = CGSize()
    @State private var circleIsDragging: Bool = Bool()
    @State private var dxKnobIsDragging: Bool = Bool()
    @State private var percentageDX: CGFloat? = nil
    
    private let maxScreenVisibilitySize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 400.0, height: 300.0)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            
            ZStack {
                
                Color.clear
                
                Color.white
                    .frame(width: maxScreenVisibilitySize.width, height: maxScreenVisibilitySize.height)
                
                Circle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
                    .offset(x: currentCircleOffset.width, y: currentCircleOffset.height)
                    .gesture(circleGesture)
                
                if let unwrappedPercentageDX: CGFloat = percentageDX {
                    Text("percentageDX: \(String(format: "%.2f", unwrappedPercentageDX*100.0))%").bold().monospaced().foregroundStyle(.black).offset(y: 50)
                }
                
                
            }
            .clipped()
            .onChange(of: currentCircleOffset) { (oldValue, newValue) in
                
                if (!dxKnobIsDragging) && (oldValue != newValue) {
                    
                    percentageDX = (newValue.width/(maxScreenVisibilitySize.width/2.0))
                    
                }
                
            }
            .onChange(of: percentageDX) { (oldValue, newValue) in
                
                if (!circleIsDragging) && (dxKnobIsDragging) {
                    
                    if let unwrappedOldValue: CGFloat = oldValue, let unwrappedNewValue: CGFloat = newValue, (unwrappedOldValue != unwrappedNewValue) {
                        
                        // I may made mistake here!
                        
                        currentCircleOffset.width -= (unwrappedNewValue*maxScreenVisibilitySize.width)/2.0
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
            VStack {
                
                Spacer()
                
                CustomSliderView(percentageDX: $percentageDX, dxKnobIsDragging: $dxKnobIsDragging)
                
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        
    }
    
    private var circleGesture: some Gesture {
        
        return DragGesture(minimumDistance: CGFloat.zero, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged() { value in
                
                circleIsDragging = true
                
                currentCircleOffset = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + lastCircleOffset.width,
                                             height: value.translation.height + lastCircleOffset.height)
                
            }
            .onEnded() { value in
                lastCircleOffset = currentCircleOffset
                circleIsDragging = false
            }
        
    }
    
}

struct CGSizePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGSize { get { return CGSize() } }
    static func reduce(value: inout CGSize, nextValue: () -> CGSize) { value = nextValue() }
}


struct CustomSliderView: View {
    
    @Binding var percentageDX: CGFloat?
    @Binding var dxKnobIsDragging: Bool
    
    @State private var lastKnobOffset: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    @State private var currentKnobOffset: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    
    @State private var currentOffsetPercentage: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    
    @State private var maxWidthSize: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    @State private var knobWidth: CGFloat = CGFloat()
    private let knobHeight: CGFloat = 25.0
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            
            ZStack {
                
                Color.gray
                
                Color.white.opacity(knobWidth.isZero ? .zero : 0.85)
                    .frame(width: knobWidth)
                    .shadow(radius: 10)
                    .offset(x: currentKnobOffset)
                    .gesture(knobGesture)
                
            }
            .preference(key: CGSizePreferenceKey.self, value: proxy.size)
            
        }
        .frame(height: knobHeight)
        .onPreferenceChange(CGSizePreferenceKey.self) { newValue in
            
            maxWidthSize = newValue.width
            
            if percentageDX == nil {
                knobWidth = newValue.width
            }
            
            
        }
        .onChange(of: percentageDX) { (oldValue, newValue) in
            
            // This part is okay; it works as expected.
            
            if (!dxKnobIsDragging) {
                
                if let unwrappedOldValue: CGFloat = oldValue, let unwrappedNewValue: CGFloat = newValue, (unwrappedOldValue != unwrappedNewValue) {
                    
                    if let unwrappedNewValue: CGFloat = newValue {
                        
                        let newPercentageDX: CGFloat = abs(unwrappedNewValue)
                        
                        let knobScale: CGFloat = 10.0
                        
                        knobWidth = (maxWidthSize - (newPercentageDX*maxWidthSize)/knobScale)
                        
                        
                        if (unwrappedNewValue >= .zero) {
                            currentKnobOffset = -(newPercentageDX*maxWidthSize)/(2.0*knobScale)
                            lastKnobOffset = currentKnobOffset
                        }
                        else {
                            currentKnobOffset = (newPercentageDX*maxWidthSize)/(2.0*knobScale)
                            lastKnobOffset = currentKnobOffset
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private var knobGesture: some Gesture {
        
        return DragGesture(minimumDistance: CGFloat.zero, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .onChanged() { value in
                
                dxKnobIsDragging = true
                
                // I need to finish this part with the help of reverse coding on .onChange(of: percentageDX)
                
                
            }
            .onEnded() { value in
                
                lastKnobOffset = currentKnobOffset
                dxKnobIsDragging = false
                
            }
        
    }
}


Please could you elaborate on how the slider is meant to work? The value of percentageDX is computed as (dragOffset / half width), so if the circle is dragged fully to the right side, the percentage is 100%. This should be represented by 10% gray space on the right of the slider, correct? Now, if the slider is dragged right, should we see dark space appearing on its left side? So when the slider has been dragged fully to the right, there will be 10% dark space on the left and the circle will be back in the middle, correct?

You got the first part correct, But this part "Now, if the slider is dragged right, should we see dark space appearing on its left side?" No, the slider dragged to the right means circle goes back to it´s start point and the slider start filling up again to 100%, no dark space appering on its left, onless you push more to right on slider from 100% and then there will be dark space on its left, in other word, this could be happen just dragging circle to left, so the dark space would be appering on the left, the code for dragging circle is correct and working right, now I need slider do the same

OK, so the width of the slider is fixed. So if there is 10% gray on the right, then it means 10% of the slider width is off-screen on the left, correct? Won't this mean, a large movement of the slider will send the circle straight off-screen?

"OK, so the width of the slider is fixed. " the only fixed part by silder would be the gray color under the white color as a ground, the white part going to have 100% at zero drag by circle, if circle get 100% move to right that means 10% move and pressing to the left part for white part of slider. and if circle get 100% move to left that means 10% move and pressing to the right part of slider.(about this better try dragging the circle to left and right for better understanding it), I do not want complecated the things more but the gray part of slider also is not fixed ...

it means by changing the size of window the gray part of slider or in other word the all part of slider can change it size as well so there is no fixed value there, as I said, lets do not make thing more complecated, we think that we do not change the size of window now, and we just drag circle or sider.

A small thing, I may messed up coding for part of ".onChange(of: percentageDX)" on contentview, that is why I could not find the issue so far, I was trying to solve the issue in part of knobGesture in CustomSliderView, it may i found the right answer but for wrong coding in ".onChange(of: percentageDX)"  in contentview I would not notice it. Maybe the all issue was wrong coding for proccessing the good data from knobGesture in bad way in part on content view.

Thank you for providing the extra information with your answers in the comments.
As far as I can understand from your answers, there is no need for the slider to change in width. It can simply occupy the full available width and then be offset in accordance with the percentage value.
So, I think it may be possible to solve in a much simpler way, with far fewer state variables and less logic. The PreferenceKey is not needed either.

The current percentage is stored in a state variable, like you already had it.
A GestureState variable is used to record the change in percentage based on the current drag movement.
The same two variables are used for the circle and for the slider.
The offset of the circle is computed from the current percentage.
Likewise, the offset of the slider is computed from the current percentage.

The advantage of using a GestureState is that it is automatically reset back to its initial value when the gesture ends.
So here is an updated version of your example. I hope it is working in the way you were wanting.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var percentageDX: CGFloat = 0
    @GestureState private var dragPercent: CGFloat = 0
    private let maxScreenVisibilitySize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 400.0, height: 200.0)

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 40) {
            Spacer()

            ZStack {
                Color.white
                Circle()
                    .fill(.red)
                    .frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
                    .offset(x: xOffsetCircle)
                    .gesture(circleGesture)
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: maxScreenVisibilitySize.width, maxHeight: maxScreenVisibilitySize.height)

            Text(String(format: "%.0f%%", (percentageDX + dragPercent) * 100))
                .font(.title2)

            CustomSliderView(percentageDX: $percentageDX, dragPercent: $dragPercent)

            Spacer()
        }
    }

    private var xOffsetCircle: CGFloat {
        (percentageDX + dragPercent) * (maxScreenVisibilitySize.width / 2.0)
    }

    private var circleGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture(minimumDistance: CGFloat.zero, coordinateSpace: .local)
            .updating($dragPercent) { value, state, trans in
                state = value.translation.width / (maxScreenVisibilitySize.width / 2.0)
            }
            .onEnded { value in
                let dPercent = value.translation.width / (maxScreenVisibilitySize.width / 2.0)
                percentageDX += dPercent
            }
    }
}

struct CustomSliderView: View {
    @Binding var percentageDX: CGFloat
    var dragPercent: GestureState<CGFloat>
    private let scalingFactor: CGFloat = 10.0
    private let sliderHeight: CGFloat = 25.0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ZStack {
                Color.gray
                Color.white
                    .offset(x: xOffsetSlider(maxWidth: proxy.size.width))
                    .clipped()
                    .shadow(radius: 10)
                    .gesture(
                        DragGesture(minimumDistance: CGFloat.zero, coordinateSpace: .local)
                            .updating(dragPercent) { value, state, trans in
                                state = -(value.translation.width / proxy.size.width) * 10
                            }
                            .onEnded { value in
                                let dPercent = -(value.translation.width / proxy.size.width) * 10
                                percentageDX += dPercent
                            }
                    )
            }
        }
        .frame(height: sliderHeight)
        .padding()
    }

    private func xOffsetSlider(maxWidth: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        -((percentageDX + dragPercent.wrappedValue) / scalingFactor) * maxWidth
    }
}



I really liked how you simplified the issue. In my original code, I was updating Color.white to avoid going outside the gray color range. In your solution, it does go outside this range, which was not my intention. However, since your code removes a lot of unnecessary complexity, I can use the .clipped() modifier on CustomSliderView to cut off the extra length of white. I would say your approach is better than mine.

I encountered a new issue with my code. What should I do if the slider reaches 100% or -100%? What if the user wants to drag it, say, to 150%? How can I solve this issue? I could create a new question, but I need some clarification to get started.

Pleased to hear the answer helped, thanks for accepting it. I just made an update to CustomSliderView, to clip to the available width. So if you have padding at the side, it no longer moves over the padding. Regarding going beyond the bounds, you might want to put a limit on the percentage, to stop it going beyond +- 100%. If in fact you want to allow that, then the circle is not going to be visible (it will be off-screen). One possible solution would be the kind of behavior I outlined in my first question.

Let’s say we don't have the issue of the circle not being visible—ignore that. And let’s say we want to support all desired movements up to 100%, 150%, 500%, ..., 10,000% on the custom slider, with the idea of keeping the slider mechanism as is. One thing that comes to mind is using different scales for different ranges on the slider. For example, if the slider is between 0%-10%, I could use a 1/10 scale; if it’s between 10%-20%, I could use a 1/100 scale, and so on. What do you think of this approach?

The idea I was suggesting in my first question is that the slider button gets smaller (less wide) as the circle is pushed out more and more. It would mean, the percentage can only be increased by dragging the circle, not by pushing the slider. But the slider can bring it back to 0.
